# Static build of Assimp using Cmake & VS2013: cannot find assimpd.pdb

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, assimp

I am trying to statically build Assimp on Windows to later make a standalone executable. Here is what I did:

1. I downloaded the 3.1.1 version and used Cmake GUI.
2. I unchecked BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and checked ASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB
3. Clicked on configure and Generate
4. Opened the solution with Visual Studio 2013 in administrator mode
5. Right cliked on ALL_BUILD and build

At this point everything worked fine. Then I tried to build INSTALL (right click > build) and it failed with:

```
file INSTALL cannot find
"C:/Users/.../assimp-3.1.1/build/code/Debug/assimpd.pdb"
```

I have two questions:

1. Should I actually build INSTALL as I only want a static build?
2. If yes, what did I do wrong/what should I do to fix this?

Thank you very much for your time!

PS: I checked the directory Debug and there is only a assimpd.lib

Comment: I would say this step is wrong `Opened the solution with Visual Studio 2013 in administrator mode` although this likely has noting to do with the missing pdb file.

Comment: I also suspect that this message is not a fatal error and can be ignored. Although you should check to see if the pdb file it is asking for exists. Make sure you turn off "hide file extensions for known types" in the folder settings for explorer so it does not hide the .pdb extension confusing the matter.

Comment: So you're saying I shoudln't open the solution via VS2013. I thought Cmake was supposed to generate "build files" and then you could build the library using VS... I'm confused.

Comment: No I am saying you do not need to build as an administrator. I never ever do that with Visual Studio / CMake generated projects ( and I use CMake daily for 6+ years).

Comment: Ok. You're way more experienced than me so I believe you :)

Comment: Actually there seems to be a problem with the static build of Assimp:
https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/271

Comment: @Gpack, this error occurred when I build shared and not static...However it was on Linux and not on Windows.